# How to change background color on tabbar on scroll in Ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I've just started with Ionic and Ionic 4, and have managed to make the toolbar transparent. However, I need it to switch to white background once the user starts to scroll. I've tried to google and understand how this is done, but can't say I've come any closer to the answer. I've never used TypeScript or much JavaScript either, which makes this a lot harder! Please help, thank you! :-)

Here's the html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <!--need to add function to this button-->
            <button ion-button icon-only>
                <ion-icon name="ios-options" isActive="false" id="filter-icon"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>


    </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen padding>
    <ion-title><h1>Explore</h1></ion-title>
</ion-content>
```

And the CSS:

```
ion-toolbar{
    --background: transparent;
    --ion-color-base: transparent !important; 
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ionic 4 variable.scss:

```
--ion-tab-bar-background: var(--ion-color-primary);                    
--ion-tab-bar-color: var(--ion-color-light); 
--ion-tab-bar-color-activated: var(--ion-color-dark);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can changes as below one of method

1. In HTML
   `<ion-toolbar color="dark"></ion-toolbar>`
2. Inside scss page file
   `--background: var(--ion-color-primary);`